# htaccess Cancel Rewrite Rule for Some Keywords

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wanted to redirect domain.com/a-page-name to domain.com/index.php?sayfa=a-page-name and used following code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ index.php?sayfa=$1 [L,NC]
```

But now I don't want to redirect domain.com/pictures, domain.com/sources How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:pictures|sources)$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ index.php?sayfa=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Did you send the .htaccess file to the ftp server in text mode (not binary) ?

Comment: Is it possible that it's not working because I'm on local? BTW other htaccess codes (that I gave) still works without any problem.

Comment: That can be the case if root directory is not the same as directory for index.php. Try with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*(?:pictures|sources)$`...

Comment: Perfect! Which one do you prefer? Which one should I use (in a server of course. on local, only 2nd one worked)

Comment: Great ! I prefer the first one. But no real difference.